# Connection is not associated with a managed connection , "Spring application in Jboss Server"

Tags: spring, jboss, jboss6.x

Below Exception is coming in specific server, issue is not consistent.

```
org.springframework.jdbc.support.MetaDataAccessException: Error while extracting DatabaseMetaData; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException:
Connection is not associated with a managed connection.org.jboss.resource.adapter.jdbc.jdk6.WrappedConnectionJDK6@49828f4c
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.JdbcUtils.extractDatabaseMetaData(JdbcUtils.java:296)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.JdbcUtils.extractDatabaseMetaData(JdbcUtils.java:320)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLErrorCodesFactory.getErrorCodes(SQLErrorCodesFactory.java:213)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.setDataSource(SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.java:141)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.<init>(SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.java:104)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.JdbcAccessor.getExceptionTranslator(JdbcAccessor.java:99)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:969)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.call(JdbcTemplate.java:1003)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.object.StoredProcedure.execute(StoredProcedure.java:144)
    at com.watsons.tfo.sp.dao.SPSaveTransactionDetail.execute(SupplierPromotionDaoImpl.java:3354)
    at com.watsons.tfo.sp.dao.SupplierPromotionDaoImpl.savePromoTransaction(SupplierPromotionDaoImpl.java:422)
    at com.watsons.tfo.sp.service.SupplierPromotionServiceImpl.savePromoTransaction(SupplierPromotionServiceImpl.java:158)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1010.invoke(Unknown Source)
```

--

```
org.springframework.dao.RecoverableDataAccessException: CallableStatementCallback; SQL [{call PKG_TFO_SUPPLIER_PROMOTION.PR_INS_SAVE_TRANSACTION_DET(?, ?)}]; No more data to read from socket; nested exception is java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: No more data to read from socket
    at com.watsons.tfo.sp.service.SupplierPromotionServiceImpl.savePromoTransaction(SupplierPromotionServiceImpl.java:160)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1010.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:309)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:110)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
    at $Proxy206.savePromoTransaction(Unknown Source)
    at com.watsons.tfo.sp.controller.SupplierPromoTransactionController.saveSupplierPromoTransaction(SupplierPromoTransactionController.java:1077)
    at com.watsons.tfo.sp.controller.SupplierPromoTransactionController$$FastClassByCGLIB$$8994f9f9.invoke(<generated>)
```

First i thought the is because of stale connection, So I have added stale connection checker in the oracle-ds.xml. But again the issue is came up

Please help me to resolve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disabling the CachedConnection Manager

```
   <Valve className="org.jboss.web.tomcat.tc5.jca.CachedConnectionValve"
    cachedConnectionManagerObjectName="jboss.jca:service=CachedConnectionManager"
    transactionManagerObjectName="jboss:service=TransactionManager" />
```

The above tag is mentioned in server.xml. this *`cachedconnectionvalve should be turned off in production server`*.

[image: CCV automatically closes all JCA connection when web request ends, in production you want to disable this.]

There are two main configuration parameters that have a direct effect on performance and scalability: cached connection manager and HTTP session replication.

The CachedConnectionManager is configured to be in the servlet container in debug mode. It's also configured in the production configuration but with debug mode off.

I commented the CachedConnectionValve at end of the server.xml file.

Also commented the CachedConnectionManager in META-INF/jboss-service.xml.

The "Connection is not associated with a managed connection" is gone and application is running fine.

**Update:**

Found one more log for the same error in the oracle log files...

Oracle version: Oracle Database 11.2.0.2

i.e  `XMLSEQUENC/EEXTRACT FAILS WITH ORA-7445[__INTEL_NEW_MEMCPY()+5395]`

This is the bug with the XML Processing in oracle DB version, Then

After instructed by oracle people, Updated the patch (11666959) for oracle .

Same is mentioned in [oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23320_01/doc.22/e22743/instapps.htm) web site.

```
11666959 is required for the release utility; XMLSEQUENC/EEXTRACT FAILS WITH ORA-7445[__INTEL_NEW_MEMCPY()+5395] IN 11.2.0.2
```